# Checking a data-attribute and applying logic is failing to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

In each div - `smallCatalogBlock`, I have a data attributed called `data-availability` with either a 'Yes' or 'No'. I am attempting to check the value of the data attribute. If it is no, I am wanting the `catalogSmallCircle`, specifically for that div to be hidden.

So far, nothing is happening.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Based on what I am attempting, the buttons for "Fastening Technology" should be hidden.

```js
var availability = $('.smallCatalogBlock').data('availability');
$('.smallCatalogBlock').each(function(index, catalogBlock){
  catalogName = $(catalogBlock).data('fill-specs');
  console.log('catalog name ' + catalogName);
  if (availability == 'No') {
   console.log(availability);
   $('.catalogSmallCircle').hide();
  }
  //Filling Circle
  $('.catalogSmallCircle', catalogBlock).html(
   '<div class="catalogSmallCircleIn" data-catalog-name='+ catalogName +'><div class="total-center"><div class="circlePlus"></div></div></div><div class="catalogCircleExpand"><div class="catalogExpandClose"></div><div class="total-center expandText"><span class="catalogName pdfSubHeader"></span><p class="dGw circleExpandText"></p><button class="catalogDownload downloadButton" name="Profile_Catalog" data-catalog-now="Profile Small Catalog Button" data-catalog-view-name="Profile Catalog">View</button><button class="catalogDownload requestButton" data-catalog-name="'+ catalogName +'">Request</button></div></div>'
  )
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCatalogWrap">
  <div class="smallCatalogBlock" data-fill-specs="Profile-Catalog" data-availability="Yes">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">Profiles and Caps</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="smallCatalogBlock comingSoonSmall" data-fill-specs="Fastening Technology" data-availability="No">
    <span class="smallCatalogTitle">Fastening Technology</span>
    <div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    if (availability == 'No') {
        console.log(availability);
        $('.catalogSmallCircle').hide();
    }
```

to

```
if ($(this).data('availability') === 'no') {
        console.log(availability);
         $(this).find('.catalogSmallCircle').hide();
}
```

Comment: This wiped all of the buttons away. Not just the ones with availability = no.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your availability variable ist outside the each-loop. Instead it should be handled like the fill-specs data attribute.